# C++: Get K smallest elements+indices from vector with ties

Tags: c++, algorithm, queue

The task is to extract `k` smallest elements and their indices from double array, possibly including more elements that are tied to the `k`-th smallest one. E.g.:

```
input: {3.3,1.1,6.5,4.2,1.1,3.3}
output (k=3): {1,1.1} {4,1.1} {0,3.3} {5,3.3}
```

[This seems like a pretty common task, but I couldn't find a similar thread on SO - which handles ties. Hopefully, I didn't miss any and didn't duplicate the question.]

I came up with the following solution, which works and seems to be fairly efficient complexity-wise. E.g. for random 1MLN doubles and `k=10` it takes ~40ms with MSVC 2013. I wonder if there's a better/cleaner/*more efficient(for large data and/or large `k`)* way to perform this task (validations for `k` value and similar things are our of scope here). Avoid allocating the queue with *all* elements? Make use of `std::partial_sum` or `std::nth_element`?

```
typedef std::pair<double, int> idx_pair;
typedef std::priority_queue<idx_pair, std::vector<idx_pair>, std::greater<idx_pair>> idx_queue;

std::vector<idx_pair> getKSmallest(std::vector<double> const& data, int k)
{
    idx_queue q;
    {
        std::vector<idx_pair> idxPairs(data.size());
        for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            idxPairs[i] = idx_pair(data[i], i);

        q = idx_queue(std::begin(idxPairs), std::end(idxPairs));
    };

    std::vector<idx_pair> result;

    auto topPop = [&q, &result]()
    {
        result.push_back(q.top());
        q.pop();
    };

    for (auto i = 0; i < k; i++)
        topPop();

    auto const largest = result.back().first;
    while (q.empty() == false)
    {
        if (q.top().first == largest)
            topPop();
        else
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Working example is [here](http://ideone.com/OYsP0h).

Comment: Just a suggestion, try cs.stackexchange.com. When it comes to algorithms, it's a far more appropriate place to ask something like this (just make your question language agnostic). Not that you won't get an answer here, but this is an algorithm question... not a C++ or stackoverflow domain type of question.

Comment: @mr.stobbe thanks for the suggestion! Along with the actual algorithm, I'm interested to hear some feedback on the actual c++ side - i.e. the use of the `priority_queue`, `partial_sum`, `nth_element`; maybe other suggestions on the code, etc.

Comment: Ahh... that makes a bit more sense. I can answer that for you right away. If you want to guarantee speed, don't use standard containers (`priority_queue` is right out). Write the minimal container necessary to meet your needs and it will be fast. Standard containers (while generally elegantly implemented overall) are meant to be _generic_ and as such probably aren't doing you any favors. `partial_sum` and `nth_element` on the other hand are naturally fully reintrant and thread safe without any kind of barriers and are really just proxy functions, so I wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: @mr.stobbe oh, good point. I actually have implemented the minimal minHeap data structure before - should try and see if it'd remove some hidden overheads of STL's container

Comment: Make a `std::vector` of pairs (value, index): `std::pair<double, size_t>`, and use `std::nth_element`. You will get an iterator `it` to the n'th element. Scan the range `[it + 1, end)` left to right comparing elements to `it->first` to find the ties.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by asker, I will suggest first copy the vector of double and use a nth_element to find out the kth element.
Then do a linear scan and get the elements that are smaller than or equal to the kth element. The Time complexity should be linear.

However, it should be careful when comparing double.

```
vector<idx_pair> getKSmallest(vector<double> const& data, int k){
    vector<double> data_copy = data;
    nth_element(data_copy.begin(), data_copy.begin() + k, data_copy.end());
    vector<idx_pair> result;
    double kth_element = data_copy[k - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        if (data[i] <= kth_element)
            result.push_back({i, data[i]});
    return result;
}
```

update: It is also possible to find the kth_element by maintaing a max heap with size at most k.

It only need O(k) memory for heap instead of O(n) memory in the nth_element method.

It needs O(n log k) time but if k is small then i think it should be comparable to O(n) method.
I am not sure about it but my reason are the heap may be cached and you don't need to spend time for copying data.

```
vector<idx_pair> getKSmallest(vector<double> const& data, int k)
{
    priority_queue<double> pq;
    for (auto d : data){
        if (pq.size() >= k && pq.top() > d){
            pq.push(d)
            pq.pop();
        }
        else if (pq.size() < k)
            pq.push(d);
    }
    double kth_element = pq.top();
    vector<idx_pair> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    if (data[i] <= kth_element)
        result.push_back({i, data[i]});
    return result;
}
```

Comment: as posted in the question, I need the indices too

Comment: @OlegShirokikh yes, you can do nth_element on a vector copy and then get the indices when you do linear search on the original vector.

Comment: do at least `k` O(n) searches to retrieve indices? Why do that instead of working with pairs at the first place?

Comment: @OlegShirokikh Maybe I made a mistake. I guess you also want the indices of elements that are tie to kth element?
then you can do like with only need one linear search
for all indice i{
if (v[i] <= kth_element)
result.push_back({i, v[i]});
}
where v is original vector and you find kth_element using nth_element on a copy of v

Comment: Not sure if your approach will work - the indices should correspond to the original container and not to partially sorted by `nth_element` vector

Comment: I will post a code example, hopefully that will explain my idea.

Comment: I see now - very nice. And this is the fastest alternative so far: faster than my version with `nth_element` perhaps b/c it eliminates the overhead of working with pairs instead of doubles, and as a result, also slightly faster on average than the alternative with `priority_queue`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution, suggested by @piotrekg2 - using `nth_element` with average O(N) complexity:

```
bool equal(double value1, double value2)
{
    return value1 == value2 || std::abs(value2 - value1) <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}

std::vector<idx_pair> getNSmallest(std::vector<double> const& data, int n)
{
    std::vector<idx_pair> idxPairs(data.size());
    for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        idxPairs[i] = idx_pair(data[i], i);

    std::nth_element(std::begin(idxPairs), std::begin(idxPairs) + n, std::end(idxPairs));

    std::vector<idx_pair> result(std::begin(idxPairs), std::begin(idxPairs) + n);

    auto const largest = result.back().first;
    for (auto it = std::begin(idxPairs) + n; it != std::end(idxPairs); ++it)
        if (equal(it->first, largest))
            result.push_back(*it);

    return result;
}
```

Indeed, the code looks a bit cleaner. However, I've run some tests and empirically this solution is slightly slower than the original one with `std::priority_queue`.

Note: The answer below by Petar offers a similar solution using `std::nth_element`, which in my experiments, performs slightly better than this one and also better than the solution using `std::priority_queue` - perhaps because of eliminating the operation on pairs and working with primitive doubles instead.